# What is an efficient way to transfer an relation defining id between two types of (JSON)entities in Python3?

Tags: python, json

I have to types of entities contacts and clubs.
Both are represented as a json object. Contacts have unique id's and clubs also have unique id's. Contacts and Clubs are stored in individual lists.

The relation between those two is, that each club can have one or more contacts.
This relation is currently stored insied the club entity. There is a key called "contacts" which lists one or more Ids of contacts.

```
{'id': '12345678', 'clubName': 'myclub', 'contacts': ['098765', '192837', '543210]}
```

However, I now need to import those datasets into another system.
In this new system, the relation is "reversed". Meaning, the information is not stored in the clubs entity but in the contacts entity. Contacts now need to hold the id's of their respective clubs and not the other way around.

I am looking for a way to transfer those id's from the clubs into the contacts.

The only way, I could think of so far is:

- Loop over all clubs and get each contact id, remember the clubs id
- Loop over all contacts, get the contact id and check whether it matches with the given contact id
- if the contact id matches, add the club's id to the contact entity

As you probably noticed, this is a pretty inefficient double or even triple loop (since a club can have multiple contacts) and will probably be very inefficient in a larger dataset.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a python dictionary of sets for each contact.
contacts = {}
Loop through each club.

- When you see a contact,
- check if contacts in dictionary
- ```
   if so, then contacts[contact] = {club} # a new set
  ```
- ```
   if not  then contacts[contact].add(club)
  ```
- When you're done the contacts list is already near your json format. You could walk through it one more time to get what you like as JSON, or you could use a package like import json to convert it with something like json.dumps(contacts)